# jquery fileupload on button click

Tags: jquery, asp.net, file-upload

I have used fileupload.js jquery plugin and followed this tutorial to implement this: [ASP.NET Ajax file upload using jQuery File Upload plugin](http://evolpin.wordpress.com/2011/09/11/asp-net-ajax-file-upload-using-jquery-file-upload-plugin/)

This works great, but as soon file is selected using the input(fileuplaod control), event is raised and uploades the file. However, I'm trying to do this only after button click.

**Here is the code:**

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="file" multiple="multiple"/>
<input id="btnSubmit" type="button" value="Start Upload"/>

    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
      //uploads file
    });
```

**Need to do something like this:**

```
  $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
       $('#fileupload').fileupload({
         //uploads file
       });
    });
```

I guess we can do this using callback option but I could not get this properly:[Callback Options](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options)

Comment: i would recommend you to rather use the original plugin as it has all that you need. check this for demo: [http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/)

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="file" multiple="multiple"/>

<script>
$('#fileupload').on('click', function(){
    //uploads file
});
</script>
```

use the 'on' in jQuery.

Greetings.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, upload files via 'add' option

**In Markup**

```
<input id="files" type="file" name="files" multiple="multiple"/>
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="file" multiple="multiple" style="display:none;"/>
<input id="btnSubmit" type="button" value="Start Upload"/>
```

**IN JQuery**

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
    var inputs = $('#files'); 
    var arr = $.makeArray(inputs); // turn the jQuery objects into an array
    var filesList = $.map(arr, function (element, index) { 
        return element.files;
    });

    $('#fileupload').fileupload('add', { files: filesList }); // upload by calling 'add'
});
```

Comment: Yograj thanks for your response.
In your given sample following line returning null value:
 var filesList = $.map(arr, function (element, index) { 
        return element.files;
    });

Comment: or am I doing wrong while reading it:
add: function (e, data) {
$.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
 alert(file.name);
}
});
}

Answer (score 2):

In your link about this plugin states:
"As the documentation states, ‘add’ defaults to submitting the data using ‘data.submit( )’. But you might want to perform a validation on the selected file, for example, that the file extension is correct. So your implementation may look like this:"

```
if(valid)
 data.submit();
```

And below is:
"Another alternative may be to instruct the upload plug-in not to start uploading the files immediately, and to validate when the user manually clicks on a certain “upload” button."

So i guess you have to just cut this `data.submit()` line and instead call this on your click button event handler.

Comment: The problem OP is having is in regards to the context of the data object. This object is only available in callbacks from the plugin, for example, when a file is selected, not when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="file" multiple="multiple" onClick="uploadFunction"/>

<script>
uploadFunction()
{
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
  //uploads file
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: thanks Ahmad: but it doesn't initiate $('#fileupload').fileupload()

Answer (score 1):

button id="buttonUpload" onclick="return ajaxFileUpload();" style="font-size: 11px">
                    Upload />

img id="loading" src="images/loading.gif" style="display: none;" /> -- to make it progress bar

In Script tag include below and modify as per your requirement

function ajaxFileUpload() {

```
        $("#loading")
.ajaxStart(function() {
    $(this).show();
})
.ajaxComplete(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});

$.ajaxFileUpload
    (
        {
            url: 'AjaxImageUploader.ashx',
            secureuri: false,
            fileElementId: 'fileToUpload',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {},
            success: function(data, status) {

            },
            error: function(data, status, e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }
    )

        return false;
    }
```